# Possibilities of fixed point-free tupels

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

> We define the sample space $\Omega:=\{\omega\in\{1,\dots n\}^n\mid \omega_i\neq\omega_j\text{ for all } 1\leq i<j\leq n\}$. We call a tupel $\omega\in\Omega$ fixed point free if for all $1\leq i\leq n:$ $\omega_i\neq i$.
> How many tupels exist that have exactly one fixpoint?

Our sample solution says:

$n\cdot D_{n-1,0}$, where $D_{n-1,0}$ is the respective Rencontre number in the setting of $n-1$ tupels and $0$ fixed points. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers)

We can choose $n$ fixed points and for the remaining $n-1$ entries there are $D_{n-1,0}$ possibilities of permutations without fixed points.

---

What I don't understand is: Why are we allowed to establish a connection between the $n$-tupels and the $n-1$ tupels?

Intuitively it makes sense but it doesn't feel rigorous. Don't we have to construct a bijection between fixed point free tupels of lenght $n-1$ and tupels of length $n$ that have exactly one fixed point? If so, how do we construct such a bijection?

Comment: To each $\omega$ having a unique fixed point $k$, associate the pair of $k$ and the map $\tilde{\omega}$ obtained by "removing" the fixed point from $\omega$ and relabeling the elements $\{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus\{k\}$ by $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$. For example, identifying each function $f:A\to B$ with its graph $\{(x,f(x)):x\in A\}\subseteq A\times B$, we will have the correspondence $$\{(1,4),(2,2),(3,1),(4,3)\} \quad\longleftrightarrow (2, \{(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)\}) $$ by relabeling $\{1,3,4\}$ as $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee,  how do we generalize this process of "removing" and "relabbeling"? It becomes clear in your example but I don't see why this allows us to say that this is possible for all tupels of a particular length and all $n$?